Next-intl gets the specified array object
My message/en.json looks like this
{
  "items": [{
    "name: "item 1",
    "price: "100",
  }, {
    "name: "item 2",
    "price: "200",
  }]
}

My page.tsx
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

export default function ProductSection() {
  const t = useTranslations() as any;

  return <>{t('items[0].price')}</>;
}

Also tried
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

export default function ProductSection() {
  const t = useTranslations('items') as any;

  return <>{t('[0].price')}</>;
}

I tried above method but get the error message:
IntlError: MISSING_MESSAGE: Could not resolve `items[0].price` in messages for locale `en`.

There is a method on the Internet to map the array object and then loop, but it is not what I want. I don’t need to loop for the time being, I just need to get the item I need.

Here's how you can loop through and array and get the messages you need github:
{
"items": {
    "item-1": {
      "title": "Item 1",
      "value": "34"
    },
    "item-2": {
      "title": "Item 2",
      "value": "1000"
    },
    "item-3": {
      "title": "Item 3",
      "value": "10000"
    },
    "item-4": {
      "title": "Item 4",
      "value": "100"
    },
    "item-5": {
      "title": "Item 5",
      "value": "5"
    }
  }
}

And you can create an array with the different keys:
[
  'item-1',
  'item-2',
  'item-3',
  'item-4',
  'item-5'
].map((key) =>
  <p key={key}>{t(`items.${key}.title`)} ({t(`items.${key}.value`)})</p>
)


I just edited my question and provide full code and error message, thanks.

Is there a particular reason for you to do it with an array inside of "items"?
Otherwise I'd recommend structuring you json like this solution form github.
It's going to be much easier to get a specific item like this and you can still make a loop later on if needed

I just want to conveniently loop when needed and maintain my commonly used format. I found that the message method of array object is not mentioned in the doc. Is this not recommended by next-intl? thanks.

I t's not recommended no, at least as far as I know. I changed my answer to show what I think is the best solution for you, hope that helps
